# Markdown of numbered list with some hyphens doesn't work as expected in preview

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, markdown-preview

I was editing [How exactly does __attribute__((constructor)) work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053029/) so the unordered list in the question was numbered to better correspond with the answer. I changed the first list item from a '-' to '1.' and in the preview block below, the rest of the list items changed to numbered items. However, when I saved my changes, only the first item was in a numbered list. In this case, the preview is probably incorrect, and should be changed to reflect what will actually be displayed in the question.

Comment: I just had this problem in [v1 of SO answer 2785191](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2785191/revisions).

Answer (score 6):

(@Jeff) No, you created a list differently than how the OP described it:

> ...unordered list in the question... I changed the first list item from a '-' to '1.'

Markup:

```
 1. ichi
 - ni
 - san
```

Looks in the preview like:

1. ichi
2. ni
3. san

But is rendered finally like:

1. ichi

   - ni
   - san

Comment: +1 this has happened to me too ... thought it was a nice shortcut, but then it didnt work >.< can we add this as a feature instead of a bug?

Comment: I encountered the same problem, but even worse due to list nesting, while composing http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2428/hoist-installation-with-concrete-walls-and-ceiling

Answer (score 0):

Let's see:

- uno

  2. dos
  3. tres

markup is:

```
- uno
2. dos
3. tres
```

[Babelmark link to above markup](http://is.gd/6a9It)

Comment: Jeff, can you clarify what you are trying to get across with this Answer? As the problem is related to the preview, we can't get much new info from just seeing the posted version.