# Preview of formatting doesn't match the actual formatting, during edit

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, markdown

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249502/c-sample-project-need-help-with-algorithm/2249536#2249536), I typed a non-numbered list, using the syntax:

```
* first point
* second point
* third point
```

And it worked perfectly. Then someone left a comment referring to "point #1" so I figured I should edit to make it a numbered list to make it easier for future commenters to refer to the various points. I switched only the first bullet from `*` to `1.` and the other two bullets automatically changed to "2." and "3." in the automatic as-you-type preview under the edit box. Then, when I submitted my edit, it still looked like this:

- first point
- second point
- third point

So I did another edit, like this:

```
1. first point
1. second point
1. third point
```

and as expected, the result was like this:

1. first point
2. second point
3. third point

I'm not sure which behavior is the correct interpretation of the markdown, but the actual interpretation didn't match the interpretation in the as-you-type edit box. Minor problem, but I figure SO is so good I might as well throw this in and maybe it will become just a tiny bit better!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Markdown of numbered list with some hyphens doesn't work as expected in preview](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35340/markdown-of-numbered-list-with-some-hyphens-doesnt-work-as-expected-in-preview)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it is a bug (testing with this answer)... Typing this:

```
1. first
* second
* third
```

previews as:

1. first
2. second
3. third

But renders as:

1. first

   - second
   - third

As to why you don't see the revision, I think that edits have the 5 minute grace period feature applied to them too, so your first revision wasn't saved because it was replaced by the second edit.

Comment: the second form is (more) correct. See http://babelmark.bobtfish.net/

Comment: Okay then. Removing the edit at the top of the question.