# Discrepancy between the WMD preview and posted lists

Tags: bug, status-completed, editor, markdown-preview, list

Mixing unordered lists and ordered lists gets you a list that follows the first list element to decide if it is an ordered or unordered list on the preview, but on the resulting post, you get a sublist of the second type inside a list of the first type.

```
1. First line
1. Second line
- Third line
```

...is shown in the Preview as:

```
1. First line
2. Second line
3. Third line
```

...but after posting is rendered as:

1. First line
2. Second line

   - Third line

Comment: Damn, I don't have enough rep to understand this post!

Comment: @Andy For your benefit, see S.Mark's script in a comment on [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49760/citing-stack-overflow-discussions/49761#49761), and my relevant comment (as a mediating step to reach the source) if you don't use Greasemonkey

Comment: @Andy: in case [the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/2e4c1b91-7276-46ea-9c5b-36196c808279/view-source) doesn't work for you, I added a code block with the original contents.

Comment: @ccornet, @voyager.  Thanks, I see it now. +1

Comment: Duplicates: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39183/preview-of-formatting-doesnt-match-the-actual-formatting-during-edit and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35340/markdown-of-numbered-list-with-some-hyphens-doesnt-work-as-expected-in-preview

Comment: @Andy, for *any* post, just using `/posts/<id>/revisions` will get you the revision "list" (including a link to "show source") even if there's only one revision and hence no clickable "edited xx ago" link is shown yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've changed the behavior of WMD to match the serverside Markdown; this will be fixed in the next build.