# Bug in preview of ordered lists

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, markdown-preview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Discrepancy between the WMD preview and posted lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50506/discrepancy-between-the-wmd-preview-and-posted-lists)

Consider the following Markdown code:

```
1. first
* second
* third
```

In the client-side preview, this will be displayed as:

> 1. first
> 2. second
> 3. third

But when I submit the answer, it will look like this:

> 1. first
>
>    - second
>    - third

---

Demonstration (2k+):

1. first

   - second
   - third

Comment: Ahaha, whoops, I wasn't quite thinking with that edit. Seeing the source does show how the demonstration is crafted, but the "point" of the demonstration is the preview, which still requires 2k. <2k users seeing the source really won't get much out of it.