# Bug in ordered list preview

Tags: bug, markdown-preview, list

When typing an ordered list, the preview of the last item is indented and restarts numbering (like an additional sublevel of the list) until any nonwhitespace character is added.  Thus, somebody looking at the preview as they enter an ordered list might see that the place they're about to type is going to appear as a sub-item, when it should be a main item, and not do so until they can figure out how to get it as part of the main list, when in fact it will jump back to the main list as soon as the person starts typing, as shown below.  This is unexpected behavior; note the consistency between list items in the source of this question (click "edit" to view) and inconsistency in its rendering, as well as how much more consistent the rendering would be with any content after the last "1." Can that be adjusted or is it an unavoidable aspect of markdown?

1. The first item.
2. The second item.
3. The third item.
  1.

I'm not mixing ordered and unordered lists as in [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50506/discrepancy-between-the-wmd-preview-and-posted-lists) or [this dupe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55111/bug-in-preview-of-ordered-lists).